# Retrieve data using joins

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables: Transfers and Outlets in below structures.

Transfers Table

```
TransID | FromOutlet | ToOutlet  
--------| -----------| ----------  
T001    |   111      |    222
```

Outlet Table

```
OutletCode | OutletDesc  
-----------|------------  
111        |ABC  
222        |XYZ
```

I want the output as follow.

```
TransId | FromOutlet | ToOutlet  
--------|------------|----------  
T001    |  ABC       | XYZ
```

I used below query to retrieve data. But, Instead of getting different outlets I got same outlet name for both columns.

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(Transfers.TransID,'') AS 'TransId',
    ISNULL(Transfers.FromOutlet,'') AS 'outletFrom' ,
    ISNULL(Outlet.OutletDesc,'') AS 'Outlets',
    ISNULL(Transfers.TOOutlet,'') AS 'outletTO',
    ISNULL(Outlet.OutletDesc,'') AS 'Outlets'


FROM    Transfers INNER JOIN Outlet ON 
    Transfers.FromOutlet = Outlet.OutletCode

WHERE (Transfers.TransID = 'T001')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the Outlet Table twice - once for `FromOutleft` and once for `ToOutlet`:

```
SELECT  TransID,
        FromOutlet,
        F.OutletDesc AS 'Outlets',
        TOOutlet,
        T.OutletDesc AS 'Outlets'
FROM Transfers 
INNER JOIN Outlet F ON  Transfers.FromOutlet = F.OutletCode
INNER JOIN Outlet T ON  Transfers.ToOutlet = T.OutletCode

WHERE  TransID = 'T001'
```

Comment: Another small problem. Rows are duplicated.How can I remove duplicate rows?

Comment: Your sample data should not cause duplicated rows with this query. If you have duplication rows you can either use the `distinct` keyword or check your data to see what's causing the duplications.